# Battlelog weapon tab doesn't show unlocks

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

Recently I've encountered a small problem at Battlelog weapon tab with some weapons(standard weapons of each class I think). As you can see here,

[image]

Battlelog says that I don't have any more unlocks for [`AK-74M`](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/AK-74M#Battlefield_3), but if you look at its' unlocks, you will see that there is a [`Rifle Scope(6x)`](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Rifle_Scope) at 300 kills and [`M145(3.4x)`](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/M145_Machine_Gun_Optic) at 350 kills. Same goes with all other standard class weapons.

Is it a bug of my Battlelog(or browser/plugin) or a bug of Battlelog itself?

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you have a plugin like BBLog installed? Have you tried erasing your browser cache and refreshing the page?

Comment: @Sentry Google Chrome. I don't think I have BBLog. Nope, didn't try it. But it also appears on my laptop

Comment: Can you equip the unlocks from 300 and 350? Because then it would really be as the answers describe: You see the kills of only one weapon, but what counts is the sum of both weapons.

Comment: @Sentry nope, couldn't equip them before unlocking. And about the sum: I doubt it, got 300 kills with `AKS-74u`(unlocked all) and 210 with `M4A1` and `M4A1` still(already) shows the unlocks. And with snipers: 116 kills with `SVD` and 61 with `MK11 MOD 0`, which makes a total of 177 kills, but still no unlocks shows

Comment: Hm, then I have not the slightest clue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after the comment I see the bug too.

It seems to be only affecting the weapons that initially are for one faction only, but you've unlocked them for both. For example I've got M27 IAR and RPK-74M unlocked for opposing force. And indeed unlock bug seems to be affecting them

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, the I haven't yet unlocked AK-74M and M16A3 for opposing force, and the bug is not affecting them.

[image]

It's not rendering issue in the browser. The HTML is for next unlock is empty (unlike for other weapons).

```
<td class="item-nextunlock last">
  <div class="item-container">
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't have problems with most of the weapons, just with some. Do you mind showing the `AK-74M`, `SVD`, `RPK-74M`, `MK11 MOD 0`, `M27 IAR`? These are the ones that show no unlocks available anymore(even though I still have to unlock quite a few)

Answer (score 1):

You are right and these weapons are the ones that can be coupled as one being US and the other RU. Another thing is that these are the last unlocked weapons of each class:

Assault: M16A3 vs AK-74
Engineer: M4A1 vs AKS-74u
Support: M27 IAR vs RPK-74M
Recon: MK11 MOD11 vs SVD

Unfortunately, I cannot think of a reason why unlocks of these weapons are not showing, it might be a bug or something.

Comment: I have the same with MK11 MOD11 vs SVD. The reason is probably that Battlelog considers them being the same and counts the total of kills for both weapon to decide whether it should display the unlocks right. So if your kill count of AK-74M + M16A3 is greater than 350, Battlelog might think you're done.